# Access response size in postman test

Tags: postman

Is it possible to access the value of the response size in my postman test cases ?

While I am able to see the response size alongside the status code and the response time (both of which i can use in my test cases using responseCode.code and responseTime) I have not been able to use it in my tests. [I tried variables like responseSize and so forth to no success]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`pm.response.responseSize` will give you the response size of the body.

Comment: Nice spot, really nice and simple

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility though not so straightforward:

The size you get in Postman is made of Body size and Headers size (just point on Size's value).
In your test area, you can recover Body size doing:
`

```
var size=0;
for (var count in responseBody) {
    if(responseBody.hasOwnProperty(count))
        size += 1;
}
console.log("BODY SIZE = " + size); // you'll see the correct value in the console for the body part
```

`

For headers I didn't manage to approach the value seen in postman.
In my case I always have the same response headers (I set them all in headers_id) and from these I do: 
`

```
headers_id=["content-encoding","content-type","date","set-cookie","transfer-encoding","x-mbs-platform-state","x-representation-exclude"];
header_size = 0;
for (var i in headers_id)
{
    myHeader=postman.getResponseHeader(headers_id[i]);
    console.log("header " + myHeader);
    console.log("- size " + myHeader.length);
    console.log("- name's size " + headers_id[i].length);
    header_size += myHeader.length; //+ headers_id[i].length; // uncomment this part if you want header content's size + header name's size
}
console.log("TOTAL HEADER SIZE = " + header_size);
```

`

Hope this helps

Alexandre

Answer (score 2):

Adding an example to Sbaddam's excellent answer:

```
pm.test("response size", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseSize).to.be.equal(1252184);
});
```